# OpenStack node not booting after forced shutdown, ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv does not exist

Tags: lvm, openstack, ubuntu-20.04, initramfs, cinder

After forcibly rebooting my OpenStack compute & block storage node, it no longer boots; how can I fix this or recover its data?

```
Gave up waiting for root file system device. common problems:
 -Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
  - check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Was self resolved.

```
# guestmount -a /dev/mapper/cinder--volumes-volume--NAME -i --rw /mnt
```

https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/modify-images.html#guestmount

Comment: How did this resolve the problem?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

My system couldn't boot after an update and wasn't prompting me to enter my LUKS passphrase for my root partition. However, I was able to boot after a manual unlock.

Note: Change `/dev/vda3` to your root partition that contains Ubuntu.

```
(initramfs) cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/vda3 ubuntu
            Enter passphrase: *****
(initramfs) exit
```

The system boots.